# How can I get my Macro to run on cell selection?

Tags: vba, excel

I am not new to programming, but I am new to using macros in Excel.  I am using Excel 2010, trying to run the following macro:

```
Sub HideUnhideCells(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim keyCell As Range
Set keyCell = Range("C9")
Dim Cells1 As Range
Dim Cells2 As Range

'Call the function on C9 cell change
If Target.Address = "$C$9" Then

    'Make Data Source available for for DRG and UCR
    If keyCell.Value = "DRG" Or keyCell.Value = "UCR" Then
        Set Cells1 = Range("C33")
        Cells1.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Set Cells1 = Range("C33")
        Cells1.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    'Make MSA special cells available if MSA is selected
    If keyCell.Value = "MSA" Then
        Set Cells1 = Range("B34:C35")
        Cells1.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Set Cells1 = Range("B34:C35")
        Cells1.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    'Make UCR cells available if UCR is selected
    If keyCell.Value = "UCR" Then
        Set Cells1 = Range("B36:C39")
        Cells1.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Set Cells1 = Range("B36:C39")
        Cells1.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    'Remove extra name cells for 1-file  and 2-file values
    If keyCell.Value = "DRG" Or keyCell.Value = "ICD-9" Or keyCell.Value = "NCCI_Edits" Or keyCell.Value = "UB04" Then
        Set Cells1 = Range("B21:C25")
        Set Cells2 = Range("B28:C32")
        Cells1.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Cells2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf keyCell.Value = "ICD-10" Or keyCell.Value = "NDC" Then
        Set Cells1 = Range("B22:C25")
        Set Cells2 = Range("B29:C32")
        Cells1.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Cells2.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Set Cells1 = Range("B21:C25")
        Set Cells2 = Range("B28:C32")
        Cells1.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Cells2.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End If
End Sub
```

I have seen several postings and tutorials that talk about this, but I can't understand why this won't work.  Cell C9 is a dropdown list, and I want this macro to run so that cells are shown / not shown based on what is selected in the list.  However, if I give it parameters (as shown above) I can't run it in the UI, and if I don't give it parameters, I can only run it manually, which doesn't help me much.

Right now, when I select something from that C9 dropdown list, nothing happens.  Can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: Use `Worksheet_Change` Event with `If not intersect(target,range("C9")) is nothing then`

Comment: As mentioned, use a `Worksheet_Change` event macro. These go into the worksheet's code sheet, not a module code sheet. (right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose *View Code* for the worksheet code sheet.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth Rout and Jeeped!  Didn't know about the worksheet's code sheet, nor that Worksheet_Change was a specific event. Put the two together and we got a winner!  Could one of you put that as the answer and I can mark this question as answered?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looked ripe for a `Select Case` treatment and there were several things to add about the `Worksheet_Change` event macro (too many for a comment) so I went ahead and wrote up a draft of the `Sub Worksheet_Change`. I'm not sure if I have interpreted all of the `If ElseIf Else End If` but perhaps you can see what I'm trying to do with this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$9" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        On Error GoTo Whoa

        Rows("21:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("28:32").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("33:39").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "DRG"
                Rows("33").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case "MSA"
                Rows("34:35").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case "UCR"
                Rows("33").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Rows("36:39").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case "DRG", "ICD-9", "NCCI_Edits", "UB04"
                Rows("21:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("28:32").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "ICD-10", "NDC"
                Rows("22:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("29:32").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
    End If
FallThrough:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume FallThrough
End Sub
```

Post back into *Comments* with any problem you have transcribing this for your own purposes and I'll try to assist.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's great!  I'm so unfamiliar with the capabilities of macros.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2824249: For your [reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640) pleasure

Comment: Rectified it. Try it now :)

Comment: Quick question: Why do you have `DRG` in three of the cases?

Comment: I guess you will have to re-write the select case.